# Measure if IN clause will get nonperformant (general purpose) - MySql?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a MYSQL question:
can anybody tell me a way how to measure if an `IN()` clause is getting nonperformance or not.

So far I am having a table which holds about 5.000 rows and the `IN()` will check up to 100 IDs. it may grow up to 50.000 in the next two years.

Thanks

***NOTE***

with `nonperformant` I mean, to be in effective, slowly, bad performance, ...

**UPDATE**
It's a decission finding problem; so the `EXPLAIN` Command in MySql does not answer my question. When the perfromance is bad, I can see it myself. But I want to know it before I start to design in a way, which might be the wrong...

**UPDATE**
I am searching for a measuring technique for general purpose.

Comment: I find your usage of the words inperformant and nonperformance confusing :p Just so you know...

Comment: sorry for my english ;-) Updated

Comment: Can you post the explain statement.  If the query plan looks good that means it should perform well with any amount of data.

Comment: I dont even have a query yet. I am searching for a measuring technique for general purpose

Answer (score 0):

you can use the mysql explain statement to get the query plan.  Just enter explain in front of your select and see what it says.  You will need to learn how to read it but it is very helpful in identifying if a query is as fast as you would expect.

mysql also does not have the best query optimizer. In my experience sometimes it is faster to run 100 simple and fast queries than to run a complicated join. This is a rare case but I have gotten performance increases from it

Comment: mysql also does not have the best query optimizer.  In my experience sometimes it is faster to run 100 simple and fast queries than to run a complicated join.  This is a rare case but I have gotten performance increases from it.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `EXPLAIN` statement to check how the query is being executed. It displays information from the optimizer about the query execution plan, how it would process the statement, and how tables are joined and in which order.

There are many times that a `JOIN` can be used in place of an `IN`, which should yield better performance. Additionally, indices make a significant difference on how fast the query runs.

We would need to see your query and an `EXPLAIN` at the very least.

Comment: The thing is, I want to know it befor, so that I can decide, if I will solve it with an IN or have to find an other way ;-)
So, I need a methodology to measure if this is a good or a bad Idea for a given amount of rows and checks

Comment: @helle Right, you put `EXPLAIN` in front of your statement (`EXPLAIN SELECT ... `)